# if someone give me a request to take some data from my apps, how can i accept the request in laravel controller?

Tags: json, laravel

The request will be in json format, the request is

```
{
"app_id": 1234,
"app_key": "our_app_key",
"bus_id": 67,
"data": [{
    "seat_id": 1
}, {
    "seat_id": 2
}]
```

}

and this is my routes.php file

```
Route::get('getBookingSeats', 'SelectBoxController@getBookingSeats');
```

below my controller function:

```
public function getBookingSeats(Request $request){

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

in my controller function how can get the json data, like app_id, app_key, bus_id, and data[seat_id, seat_id]. Is it possible if yes how? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are trying to do, but the request received must be a `POST` request if you are getting the JSON data in the request. If it is, do the following:

**Route:**

```
Route::post('getBookingSeats', 'SelectBoxController@getBookingSeats');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getBookingSeats(Request $request)
{
    $app_id = $request->app_id;
    $app_key = $request->app_key;
    $bus_id = $request->bus_id;
    $seat_IDs = $request->data;

    // use the data however you want and create your response

    return response()->json('data' => $data);
}
```

Comment: how can i use post method in routes.php for the request?

Comment: Just like in my answer above. A post request is sent by the sender via a `Form` or an app like `Postman`. Your Laravel app watches for the request in the route if your route is listed in routes file. With `GET` request, you are limited to the data listed in the URL. With `POST` request, you can send a JSON invisible in the URL. Also, Laravel 5.4 comes with two routes file: `routes\web.php` for web requests if you are building views with Laravel and `routes\api.php` for http requests from other apps. Each new line in your routes file is for a separate route. You can list as many as you want.